# Unity 5.6 Mac 2D Project Build Won't Run

Tags: macos, unity-game-engine, 2d, macos-sierra

I have a Unity 5.6 2D project that I've created on my Mac (macOS Sierra).  The game plays fine when I run it inside of Unity.  However, when I "build and run", it appears to build fine (it creates the application), but it never runs.  I have sent the project to another user who is able to successfully build his projects, but he has the same issue when trying to build mine.  I've tried both an x86x64 and Universal build, but I have the same results.  Application doesn't show in Activity Monitor either.

HELP - I need to turn this in for a class!!!!

Thanks!

Comment: Are you building it for mac? What is the file extension? Please provide more information and some screen-shots would be nice. I hope we can work this out :)

Comment: Did you add the correct scene to the Build Settings?

Comment: @Programmer if that was the case, then it would probably just select the main/open scene.

Comment: Thank you!  The project only has one scene (so far), and it is listed in the build settings.  Unfortunately, there's nothing to screenshot.  After the build dialog (where it shows progress), that dialog goes away and nothing else happens.  I don't get the "build successful" message.  If I double click on the application, nothing happens that I can see (it never shows as a running application and I don't see it in Activity Monitor).  I am building on a Mac for a Mac (although I've tried doing a Universal build as well).  This is a 2D project using Sprites (if that matters).

Comment: Build for Windows and tell us what happens. I want to make sure that this is not a platform specific problem.

Comment: I'm seeing this in the log (I did finally see the "build successful" message): Native extension for OSXStandalone target not found

Comment: Windows does not appear as an option.

Comment: See [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/answers/1067111/view.html)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Programmer and @Coolq B for all your help. I was able to get it to work by exporting everything out of my project, and import it into a new project.  Clearly, there was something corrupt in the original project.